# How do I mount iso files inside a virtual drive?

Tags: installation, mount, playonlinux

If I want to run a program from a ISO but the program runs in Windows, thus running it from Play on Linux. I would like to know if I have to install the mounting program inside the virtual drive through Play on Linux, or if it doesn't matter. Also what would be the step by step way of doing this, and what would be the best and easiest programs for tasks like this?

Comment: I am not sure, but you may try: - Install one of: acetoneiso, furiusisomount or gmountiso - 'Configure Wine' &rarr; Drives &rarr; Add: drive letter - path where iso was mounted

Comment: Also if the program expects to read a real CDROM device, you can use [CDEmu](https://cdemu.sourceforge.io/) to have linux create a virtual CDROM device

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and I found out the simplest way for usage.

- Mount the .iso with `sudo mount -o loop /path/to/.iso /cdrom`
- copy everything found on `/cdrom` to a subfolder of your PlayOnLinux program, e.g. `~/.PlayOnLinux/Wineprefix/YourVirtualDrive/disc_c/your-iso-name`
- Open PlayOnLinux
- click on your Program once, klick on "Configure" at the left.
- click 'configure Wine' → Drives → Add: drive letter → as location path you chose the before created folder `~/.PlayOnLinux/Wineprefix/YourProgram/disc_c/your-iso-name` (I couldn't navigate there, since I didn't find hidden folders in that navigator)
- make sure there is a tick next to "cd-Rom"
- leave Wineconfig saving changes.
- Unmount the mounted .iso with `sudo umount /cdrom`

--- from now on, the CD-Rom is always "mounted" within Wine just for that specific program without any manual mounting needed. Wine Rocks!

Cheers